# 2 tables joined but it breaks on speical variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have joined two tables, it works well with $_GET['p'] when its only letters but when i have cases like 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, it breaks and nothing is displayed except for a white background on entire website.

Table testcheck

```
meny | subtitle | doknamn   | store

1a   | word     | 123.txt   | word_sub

1b   | fruit    | test.txt  | fruit_sub

1c   | food     | gru.txt   | food_sub
```

Table testdok

```
meny | sökord 

1a   | apple

1b   | dsasd

1c   | asda
```

HTML

```
<a href="?p=1a">link with numbers and letters.</a>
<a href="?p=test">Link with letters</a>
```

if i press the first link i will go to a "new" page and everything will be white. but if i press second link content will display.

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$page = $_GET['p'];
$page = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$page);

$visadok = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *
FROM testdok
RIGHT JOIN testcheck
ON testdok.meny=testcheck.meny WHERE meny='$page'") or die();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($visadok)){
$ord = $row['sökord'];  
echo $ord ;
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that preg_replace()?

Comment: Blank page usually means error. Check your error log file or throw in a couple of `echos` to see how far your code reaches

Comment: @AllInOne: it's a simplistic sanitization. not reliable, but about as useful as addslashes() would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
ON testdok.meny=testcheck.meny WHERE meny='$page'") or die();
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^-----
```

is pointless, especially while developing. Since it'll simply exit on failure, you'll never get told WHY it failed. At minimum it should be

```
... or die(mysqli_error($conn))
```

so you'll get an idea of what went wrong.

The real problem is

```
ON testdok.meny=testcheck.meny WHERE meny='$page'") or die();
                                     ^^^^^---here
```

That field name is ambiguous, since you've got a `meny` in **BOTH** tables. Its hould be `WHERE testdok.meny` or `WHERE testcheck.meny`

Comment: it does work now kinda, But it will repeat it self so when i enter a new word it will display several times depending on how many words i have in testdok

Comment: Nvm, i figured it out with the repeating process. Thanks for pointing out my error part couldt wrap my head around it.